# Return IP address using unique MAC vb.net

Tags: vb.net, macos, ip

i want to create an app that search the LAN for a specific MAC address and returns the IP address of the device..

Comment: vb.net and osx, strange combination ...

Comment: @fvu Not if a certain someone is mistaking MAC address for macintosh address. Wouldn't that be funny though?

Comment: Not likely. If you know the device name, and the PC is turned on, you can get the MAC address. 
There are tools that will scan LAN segments for live PCs that will return MAC addresses. Search: NMAP